# Eclipse debug "Attach to Application": Select Process popup not showing

Tags: debugging, eclipse-cdt

I have the following problem: I want to debug an application in Eclipse via "C/C++ Attach to Application". For this I have set a corresponding debug configuration. However, as soon as I click on "Debug", no popup window appears where I can select a process.

I have tried the same on another computer. There everything works strangely enough. Even without having a project in the workspace! A reinstallation didn't help either.

Is it maybe because of the gdb installation? There is nothing in the eclipse log files either. Has anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself: The problem was a corrupted MinGW installation. With the latest MinGW version, everything works as it should.